# DHCP server for ad-hoc wifi network

Tags: redhat, dhcp, wifi, adhoc-network

I have a computer running Red Hat. I would like to host a HTTP server on it. This server has only a WIFI interface.

How to configure a DHCP server on it?

The configuration file (`/etc/dhcpd.conf`) looks like:

```
subnet 220.9.181.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option domain-name              "example.com";
        option domain-name-servers       220.9.181.220;

        option time-offset              -18000;     # Eastern Standard Time

    range 220.9.181.221 220.9.181.225;
}
```

I have restarted the DHCP service many times but with no result. How to specify that the interface is not `eth0` but `wlan0`?

Comment: http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch08_:_Configuring_the_DHCP_Server#.UUh59xzFV8E

Comment: That's almost 20 years old. What you _should_ do is get rid of it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Or donate it to a museum.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Only 12 years old :)

Comment: Still, it's much too old to be allowed anywhere near a network.

Comment: It won't be connected to any network. It will just create its own.

Comment: @Maxbester You've asked how you would reach it by Wi-Fi - so it will very much be on your network.

Comment: So? I have nothing on it. Even if there are security issues, there will be no consequences.

Comment: @Maxbester `Even if there are security issues, there will be no consequences.` <-- There is so much wrong with that statement. For the sake of your professional reputation please install an operating system from *this decade* (or at least explain why you *can't* so people don't think you're a complete lunatic.)

Comment: Let's I am aware of the risks but I cannot update this system. Couldn't you just answer my question?

Answer (score 1):

The interface is determined by the subnet.

If your wlan0 adapter is in the 220.9.181.0 it should "just work".

That's not an internal IP range however, so I'm thinking it's either misconfigured or your running a rather advanced configuration (one only people who really, really know what they're doing should be running).

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. I think I have found a problem. The DHCP may not be installed correctly. `service dhcpd status` returns nothing. What could I do?

Comment: @Maxbester Is the DHCP daemon actually running? It's possible that there is no `status` action defined in the RC script...

Comment: Well it seems that it doesn't run. Nothing in `ps aux`

Comment: 'service dhcpd start'? Probably need to check /var/log/messages for any errors if it's not starting.

Comment: Nothing in logs but it doesn't start...